# Installation Sitecore 10.1.1 SIA error

Tags: installation, sia

I am trying to Install `Sitecore 10.1.1`, while on first step, in prerequisite installation, I am getting below error:

The term `Get-PackageProvider` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
The term `Install-PackageProvider` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
The term `Install-Module` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
The term `Get-PSRepository` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
The term `Register-PSRepository` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
The specified module `SitecoreInstallFramework` with version `2.3.0` was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

can any one help ?

Comment: Do you have proxy set? Turn off proxy and try again

Comment: there is no proxy set. the issue looks mostly like version of Power shell mismatch. still investigating :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to debug, I got it working. Ensure your PowerShell is having all the modules required to work.
in my case when I pasted the code `"Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PackageManagement`

it only showed me  `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` directory with 2 versions.

but when you are running the SIA exe, it will try to look for Powershell in
`C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` directory.

**Solution:**
All I did is copied the `Configuration` and `Modules` folder and pasted into this path.

I think we need to add the PowerShell path to Environment Variable `Path`.
the only error you might get after that is version Upgradation. which can be easily achieved.

I hope this helps others.